# How to position second div over first div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/75qj3kgL/)

z-index cannot be set to -1, positioning cannot be changed for first and second div.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.second {
  height: 120px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 1999;
}

.first {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

Comment: *positioning cannot be changed for first and second div* You mean you cannot specify `position` property or you cannot change the html structure?

Comment: You can nest the second div inside the first div, If allowed

Comment: position for first should be absolute and no positioning for the second

Comment: and why? position:relative will change nothing and will simply fix your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply a transformation (without visible effects) on the second div e.g.

```
transform: scale(1);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cbeaw84h/

Comment: the same thing if we consider (1) filter (2) clip-path (3) will-change (4) mask (5) perspective ...etc

Answer (score -2):

Position your second div:

```
.second {
  height: 120px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 1999;
  position: relative;  // This
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You should use position: relative and they'll overlay.

```
.second {
  position: relative;
  height: 120px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 1999;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you cannot touch the CSS code really, simply nest the second div inside the first.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.second {
  height: 120px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 1999;
}

.first {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="second"></div>
</div>
```